# Terminal error: Node.js environment variables are disabled

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh

Starting today I receive the following error in my terminal (iTerm2, zsh shell, MacOS Sonoma) when I run some commands, for example when opening VSCode with the `code .` command:

```bash
[0201/192142.001386:ERROR:node_main.cc(135)] Node.js environment variables are disabled because this process is invoked by other apps.
```

I have no idea when it started or how, nothing was changed as far as I can recall, and I cannot find information about that particular error code.

The command actually opens VSCode, but I get the error/warning every time.

Comment: If this happens only when running _code_, you better tag the question for _vscode_ and _nodejs_. Also I would remove the _terminal_ tag. And, post this on i.e. [su], because the question is not related to programming.

Comment: I also noticed something like this two weeks ago and it is still happening.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like it is an issue, I can see the report on Github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/204005